# Dash lines on canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I use canvas to paint with other people at the same time. But the lines are broken, how to fix it in the code?

```
socket.on('drawLine', (data) => {
    const line = data.line;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(line[0].axisX * width, line[0].axisY * height);
    context.lineTo(line[1].axisX * width, line[1].axisY * height);
    context.stroke();
   });

    function mainLoop() {
        if (mouseSettings.click && mouseSettings.move && 
                                 mouseSettings.previousPosition) {

        socket.emit('drawLine', {line: [mouseSettings.position, 
                              mouseSettings.previousPosition]});

        mouseSettings.move = false;
    }

    mouseSettings.previousPosition = {axisX: mouseSettings.position.axisX, 
                                      axisY: mouseSettings.position.axisY};
    setTimeout(mainLoop, 25);
}

mainLoop();
```

Server Node.JS

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
let historyPicture = [];

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    for (let index in historyPicture) {
        socket.emit('drawLine', {line: historyPicture[index]});
    }

    socket.on('drawLine', (data) => {
        historyPicture.push(data.line);
        io.emit('drawLine', {line: data.line});
    });
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K87G.jpg)

Comment: Why are you using a timeout?

Comment: We check every 25ms if the mouse is clicked, was moved and has a previous position. We need two points to draw a line after all 
If all three conditions are true, we send a "drawLine" message to the server and reset the "mouse.move" to "false". The current mouse position "mouse.position" is stored in the previous position "mouse.previousPosition" for the next time the mainLoop is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different [`lineCap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineCap). Before drawing the line,

```
context.lineCap = 'round';
```

The default line cap, `"butt"`, squares off the line exactly at the endpoint. When you draw the next line going in another direction, it gets squared off at a different angle, creating the gaps you're seeing. The `"round"` line cap "draws a circle" at the endpoint. Since circles are rotationally symmetrical, no gap is created.

```js
let context = document.getElementById('thin').getContext('2d');
drawLines(context);

context = document.getElementById('butt').getContext('2d');
context.lineWidth = 20;
drawLines(context);

context = document.getElementById('round').getContext('2d');
context.lineWidth = 20;
context.lineCap = 'round';
drawLines(context);

function drawLines (context) {
  const path = [[0, 0], [0, 30], [30, 30], [30, 0], [60, 0], [60, 30]];

  context.translate(30, 30);
  for (let i = 0; i < path.length - 1; ++i) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(path[i][0], path[i][1]);
    context.lineTo(path[i + 1][0], path[i + 1][1]);
    context.stroke();
  }
  context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
figure{display:inline-block;margin:0 10px;}figcaption{text-align:center;}
```

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption>Thin lines</figcaption>
  <canvas id="thin" width="120" height="90"></canvas>
</figure>
<figure>
  <figcaption>Default cap (butt)</figcaption>
  <canvas id="butt" width="120" height="90"></canvas>
</figure>
<figure>
  <figcaption>Round cap</figcaption>
  <canvas id="round" width="120" height="90"></canvas>
</figure>
```

Comment: Maybe you can tell me how to properly send and process information on the server when I change the line thickness and color?

Comment: That's a different question, and you should ask it as such.

Comment: Thank you for help. Now let's create a new question :)